# I am not able to create chat dailog 1 to 1 user with name using Quickblox sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, chat, quickblox

I am not able to create chat dailog 1 to 1 user with name using Quickblox sdk.

when i create dialog with single user,dialog created successfully but dailog name showing 0.

Thanks

Comment: will you please give su some code

Comment: Thanks Narendra for reply , i have resolved my problem.